# Multiple path variables in one url

Tags: java, url, resttemplate, query-string, path-parameter

I am trying to construct a URL that can take in multiple ids at once so I am able to return two people at once, but I am getting a number format exception

```
String url = "http://test.com/Services/people/{id}/Identifier"
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("id", {"1234","5678"});
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
                                    .queryParam("DOB", "myDOB");
String uriBuilder = builder.build().encode().toUriString();
restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity,
                class_p, params);
```

This is getting a number format exception from passing in multiple ids, is there a way to do that in a different format?

Answer (score 2):

`GET /Services/people/42` is a request for "people" resource with id `42`.

A request for multiple people by some criteria is not a resource request, but a *query*, so should use query parameters.
E.g. `GET /Services/people/find?id=13&id=29`
or maybe `POST /Services/people/find` with payload `{"id": [1234, 5678]}` *(Content-Type: application/json)*.

What you're trying to do is wrong, for a RESTful service.

Comment: More typically `id=13,29`.